# Use try-catch insetead of then-response

Tags: javascript

Is it's possible to rewrite next code with try-catch? I have heard that modern JS support it.

```
{
  // GET /someUrl
  this.$http.get('/someUrl').then(response => {

    // get body data
    this.someData = response.body;

  }, response => {
    // error callback
  });
}
```

Comment: [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: Have a look at `async/await` if you want to use `try/catch` blocks. Or use `.then().catch()` instead of providing two functions to `.then()`. Or just rethrow the error inside the error callback and wrap the entire block inside a `try/catch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by try catch I assume you are referring to async/await introduced in ES6. It's worth bearing in mind that async/await only works on promise objects and performs exactly the same function but just provides you a more synchronous way to write your code that is (in most situations) easier to read.

Using async await the promise will resolve and return that value and then proceed to the next line of code, any exceptions can be handled in a catch block like so:

```
const someFunc = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await this.$http.get('/someUrl');
        console.log(response);
    } catch(err){
        // Error handling
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: `const someFunc = async () => ` could this be simplified?

Comment: If you prefer the old syntax you could write the function definition as `async function doSomething()`.

Answer (score -1):

While many may point you to `async`/`await` so you can use the actual `try`/`catch` keywords, I think it's more important to understand the code you have and make an informed decision. Most importantly, promises already handle the `try`/`catch` for you. Lets dive in.

In this code, you are dealing with promises.

```
goDoSomething().then(callThisFunctionWithResultsWhenDone);
```

One of my favorite properties of Promises are that they already handle 
`try`/`catch` for you.

```
goDoSomething()
  .then(doSomethingThatThrows)
  .catch(doSomethingWithYourError)
  .then(otherwiseKeepGoing)
```

Notice I used the `.catch` instead of passing an error handler in the same line. The inline error handler doesn't do what you may expect so I avoid it. Using `.catch()` allows you to intelligently handle asynchronous errors by short-circuiting a series of operations or handling errors from a series of steps individually without breaking out of the pipeline.

```
goDoSomething()
  .then(throwError)
  .then(thisIsSkipped)
  .then(thisToo)
  .catch(handleErrorButDontRethrow)
  .then(doThisWithOrWithoutError)
  .then(finishUp)
```

I always like to think of this style as a pipeline. Each `catch` statement catches any errors above it going up to the previous `catch`.

So, in your case:

```
$http.get(...)
  .catch(handleRequestError)
  .then(process)
  .catch(handleProcessingError)
```

This would handle all possible errors but usually to handle the request error you actually would skip the processing step so then:

```
$http.get(...)
  .then(process)
  .catch(handleProcessingError)
```

Likewise, whatever calls this block may just want to skip the next block if the processing failed. Then you are left with:

```
$http.get(...)
  .then(process)
```

If you find yourself re-throwing then maybe you should remove the catch and let it bubble.

IMO this is much more idiomatic JS code. The style introduced with `async`/`await` is a bit more familiar if you learned other languages first but it brings a very imperative feeling with it. In order to have the flexibility to handle each async operation individually your `async`/`await` code would need to look like this:

```
let intermediateStateStorage;

try {
  intermediateStateStorage = await goDoSomething();
} catch {
  handleThis();
} 

try {
  intermediateStateStorage = await process(intermediateStateStorage);
} catch {
  handleThisOne();
}
```

This seems verbose compared to:

```
goDoSomething()
  .catch(handleThis)
  .then(process)
  .catch(handleThisOne)
```

Neither are bad and I obviously have preference but I thought you'd like to know what you are dealing with so you can make an informed decision.